# Duplicate Rule won't fire

Tags: duplicate-management

I've created a custom matching rule and duplicate rule to stop Duplicate Accounts being created.

My criteria is as follows

> (Name and Address Line 1) OR
>
> (Name and postcode) OR
>
> (Name and Town/City) OR
>
> (Address Line 1 and Postcode) OR
>
> (Address Line 1 and Country)

I have excluded certain current user profiles on the duplicate rules. Both are active.

I can't understand why it isn't firing. I have logged in as another user (system admin are exempt), created an account with same name and same address line 1 for example and I was not blocked from creating it.

It only seems to block me when all fields in the rule are exactly the same.

Can anyone help?
[image]

Comment: In the screenshot I can see the Active flag unchecked. Anything to do with it?

Comment: I had deactivated it to edit it when I took the screenshot so please ignore that. It was definitely active!

Comment: What is the profile for the user that you logged in as?

Comment: I am logged in as a sales user

Answer (score 0):

The criteria is not in the correct format, I have updated it to:
((Address Line 1 OR postcode OR Town/City) AND (Account Name)) OR ((Address Line 1 and Country))

((1 OR 2 OR 3) AND (4)) OR ((5 AND 6))

It is now working as expected!